# To find a file name with some similar characters as another file in unix

Tags: unix

I have two files with some similar string in name, I want to search second file with correspondent to another file in unix

For Eg:-

```
FileName1: - abc.flag.1502624856
FileName2:-  abc.n.1502654789
```

My doubt is when I find flag file how to find correspondent n file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Answer (score 0):

`man agrep`:

```
NAME
       agrep - search a file for a string or regular expression, with approxi‐
       mate matching capabilities
```

Let's try it:

```
$ ls | grep -v abc.flag.1502624856 > file       # remove the searched file 
$ agrep -B -y abc.flag.1502624856 file
agrep: 1 word matches within 8 errors
abc.n.1502654789
```

Since it's *approximate pattern matching* there might be false positives.

Comment: instead of just giving  direct answers, first OP must be asked for efforts she/he has put in..